# npm ERR, when i npm install react-pin-input --save

Tags: reactjs, npm

PS E:\ناهور کلون\nahoorclone\nohour> npm install react-pin-input --save

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: nahor@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.4.2 || ^16.2.0" from react-pin-input@1.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-pin-input
npm ERR!   react-pin-input@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-12-07T12_44_04_659Z-debug.log
```

my npm is the latest version but I get this error. what is the problem? how can I install react-pin-input?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your using React 17 and react-pin-input doesn't support 17 yet. You'll need to downgrade your react version to 16 to use that npm package.